# UWP VPN profile didn't create VPN connection

Tags: uwp, vpn

I created a VPN profile, but settings didn't set: name, password and authentication method. I tried to run project as administrator and it didn't also worked. What's the problem?

```
  auto mgr = ref new VpnManagementAgent();

  auto  profile                          =   ref new VpnNativeProfile();
  profile->AlwaysOn                      =   true;
  profile->NativeProtocolType            =   VpnNativeProtocolType::L2tp;
  profile->UserAuthenticationMethod      =   VpnAuthenticationMethod::PresharedKey;
  profile->ProfileName                   =   "TestVpn";
  profile->RememberCredentials           =   true;
  profile->RequireVpnClientAppUI         =   true;
  profile->RoutingPolicyType             =   VpnRoutingPolicyType::ForceAllTrafficOverVpn;
  profile->Servers->Append("101.99.74.214");  

  auto profileStatus    = mgr->UpdateProfileFromObjectAsync(profile);

  auto credentials      = ref new PasswordCredential();
  credentials->UserName = "vpn";
  credentials->Password = "vpn";  

  auto connectStatus  = mgr->ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(profile, credentials);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Do you declare the Capability of **networkingVpnProvider** in `Package.appxmanifest`, which is a restricted capability. For more information, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capability-list).

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT Hi, I added `<CapabilityName="privateNetworkClientServer" /><Capability Name="networkingVpnProvider" />` in `Package.appxmanifest`. But it didn't help.

Comment: The uwp limit it. My friend try to do it in two years ago but he still fail.

Comment: You could try manually editing the pbk file inside the appdata for the application container - if you want to programmatically store the username and password. It would probably involve some hacking comparing the values of the pbk after setting the user name and password from the ui,

Answer (score 0):

VPN cisco commands, internet

routerconfig: interface FastEthernet0/1
routerconfig if: ip address  ( ip ) (subnet) internet address

routerconfig: interface tunnel 1

routerconfig if : (ip) ( subnet )

routerconfig if : tunnel source fastethernet0/1
routerconfig if : tunnel destination ( other internet provider )

routeconfig: ip route  static  ( ip - sub - ip )

Show ip interface tunnel 1